# jQuery disable multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple JQuery slider, and I'm having trouble with the .on('click') function, if I click the next or prev button too fast it exceeds the value I expect.

[image: Jquery Simple Slider]

```
var currentSlide = 1;
var $slider = $(".slides");
var slideCount = $slider.children().length;
var slideSpeed = 500;
var slideMarginLeft = -900;
var slideMarginRight = 0;

$(".prev").on('click',function(){
if(currentSlide > 1){   
    $slider.animate({marginLeft : slideMarginLeft + 1800} , slideSpeed, function(){
        slideMarginLeft +=900;
            currentSlide--;
            console.log(currentSlide);
        });
}
});


$(".next").on('click',function(){
if(currentSlide < 5){   
    $slider.animate({marginLeft : slideMarginLeft} , slideSpeed, function(){
        slideMarginLeft -=900;
        currentSlide++;
        console.log(currentSlide);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Why not call `currentSlide++;` before the `.animate` ?

Comment: Please include your html too or what would be even better is to create a snippet the reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var currentSlide = 1;
var $slider = $(".slides");
var slideCount = $slider.children().length;
var slideSpeed = 500;
var slideMarginLeft = -900;
var slideMarginRight = 0;


function previousClickCallback(animationCallback){
    return function(){
        if(currentSlide > 1){   
            $slider.animate({marginLeft : slideMarginLeft + 1800} , slideSpeed, () => {
                slideMarginLeft +=900;
                currentSlide--;
                console.log(currentSlide);
                $(".prev").once('click',previousClickCallback);
            });
        } else {
          $(".prev").one('click',previousClickCallback);
        }
    }
}

function nextClickCallback(){
    return function(){
        if(currentSlide < 5){   
            $slider.animate({marginLeft : slideMarginLeft} , slideSpeed, () => {
                slideMarginLeft -=900;
                currentSlide++;
                console.log(currentSlide);
                $(".next").once('click',nextClickCallback);
            });
        } else {
         $(".next").one('click',nextClickCallback);
        }
        
    }
}


$(".prev").one('click',previousClickCallback);
$(".next").one('click',nextClickCallback)
```

This should do, click event gets registered only once and once the callback for animation is done then only click event is registered again and that will stop from continuously firing events

Comment: I like the logic but console says that .once() is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .next class is assigned to only one button.